# Como recuperar as imagens de um dispositivo android através de uma data?

Tags: android, imagem

Preciso recuperar todas as imagens(interna e/ou externa) que está no meu dispositivo, mas preciso filtrar essa busca por uma data. Exemplo: preciso buscar todas as fotos tiradas no dia 10/02/2016.
Só para curiosidade, depois de conseguir essa lista, irei preencher um recyclerview com as imagens recuperadas, essa parte eu sei fazer.

Já procurei horas e não consegui encontrar nada que possa me ajudar.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Enquanto ninguem responde, veja se isso te dá um "Norte" de como resolver isso: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2390177/5524514

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `lastModified()` da classe `File`:

```
File file = new File("seu_path.jpg");
Date dataImagem = new Date(file.lastModified());
Log.i("Data do arquivo @ : "+ dataImagem.toString());
```

Comment: Esse método me retorna a data da última modificação de um arquivo (sendo que eu preciso informar qual arquivo), não é disso que preciso, eu tenho que recuperar as imagens de uma determinada data, por exemplo, recuperar as imagens que foram criadas no dia 16/02/2016.
Eu informo a data e recupero as imagens daquele dia.